# How to check for API availability in Xcode 9

Tags: objective-c, ios10, foundation

I'm using he `UserNotification` framework that is available only in iOS 10. I am declaring a method that uses this framework and so far, I have been doing the check for the availability as follows:

```
@interface MyService : NSObject
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 100000
    -(BOOL)handleWillPresentNotification:(UNNotificationContent *)notificationContent;
#endif
@end
```

XCode 9 beta was just release and with this code I get a warning

> 'UNNotificationContent' is partial: introduced in iOS 10.0
>   Annotate 'handleWillPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence

The question is how do I annotate this in Objective C code the entire method? I know that Xcode 9 introduced the

```
if (@available(iOS 10, *)) {
    // iOS 10 ObjC code
}
```

but how do I wrap the entire method (including its signature) in it?

cheers

Comment: Where is this new @available syntax documented?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Comment: Do you develop framework ? Looks like you need annotation for other developers.

Comment: yes I do. I need to support different versions of xcode for compilation and different versions of iOS for runtime ...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

to answer my own question: I need to mark the method using the `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS` macro as follows:

```
-(BOOL)handleWillPresentNotification:(UNNotificationContent *)notificationContent NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0);
```

Comment: I think `API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0))` is more generic than the `NS_ABAILABLE_IOS` as the former is defined in clang header and the latter is defined in Foundation framework.